# How to find a solution to the elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

We know that one solution of the given elliptic curve is (2, 1) and we have to find another rational solution such that $x$ is not equal to 2 by drawing a tangent to the curve at (2, 1).

> $$y^2=x^3- 7$$

However, by drawing a tangent at (2, 1), the line does not intersect the curve at any other point. How do I get another solution?

Comment: There is an intersection. see picture at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve and figure out, roughly, how the picture for $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ should be changed to get your picture; I get that it should both move a bit to the right and straighten out somewhat. Worth checking that carefully

Comment: The tangent does intersect the curve later on. May be your viewing area was too small? But you can also work it out algebraically.

Comment: It is possible that the tangent makes order three contact with the ellipctic curve, when there truly would not be another point of intersection. But then the tangent will go "through the curve". Here the tangent is "locally above the curve". Because far away from origin we have $y\approx x^{3/2}$, the elliptic curve is guaranteed to catch up with the tangent line and cross over it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes probably my viewing area is small. I used wolfram alpha to plot the curve and can't figure out how to expand it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how do I work it out algebraically? I don't know the group law of an elliptic curve

Comment: Paradox: Apparently you do know implicit differentiation? Using that (or simply solving for $y$ and differentiating) you should be able to show that the tangent at $(2,1)$ has slope $6$. So the equation of the tangent is $y-1=6(x-2)$ or, equivalently $y=6x-11$. So at the points of intersection we have
$$(6x-11)^2=x^3-7.$$ You can find the solution of that cubic easily enough because we know that $x=2$ must be a double root. The third root gives you the point of intersection. Or you can use the point-doubling formula like Timbuc did.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh right. Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the group law (of an elliptic curve)? Assuming we're on a field of characteristic $\;\neq 2,3\;$ ,we can define:

$$t:=\frac{3\cdot 2^2}{2\cdot 1}=6$$

$$x_1:=t^2-2\cdot2=32\\y_1:=1+6(32-2)=181$$

and we get a new solution $\;(32\,,\,\,181)\;$

[image]

Comment: I was planning on answering, and wanted to first look at the picture. You beat me to solving and answering (+1, of course), so I took the liberty of adding the picture of the elliptic curve together with the tangent line at the point of interest. If you don't want your terse answer tarnished by something like that, please let me know, and I'll remove it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Paljon kiitoksia. It looks much better with the graph and adds a very nice geometric flavour to the answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How did you draw the picture?

Comment: @pushpen.paul I used Mathematica. The commands were first `In[1]:= EC = ContourPlot[y^2 == x^3 - 7, {x, 0, 40}, {y, -20, 200}]`, then
`In[2]:= tangent= Plot[6x-11,{x,0,36}]`, and then `In[3]:= Show[{EC,tangent}]`. I don't know if Wolfram Alpha can be coerced to do the same.